# One handlebars #each not working on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, deployment, handlebars.js

So all of my code works on local and heroku but just one {{#each}}. What I'm trying to do is list some topic related ideas to my page. It works locally but not on heroku any help please?[Pic of heroku site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8xKV.png).  [Pic of localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqKQD.png)

This is the code

`{{#each idea.toIdeas}}
    <li class="list-group-item"><a href="/ideas/show/{{id}}">{{title}}</a></li>
 {{/each}}`

[Link to the site](https://ideabraining.herokuapp.com/)
[Git Repo](https://github.com/sebbersk/IdeaBraining)